# List of 2013 US National Merit Scholars

Tags: funding, united-states, undergraduate, reference-request, education

I am doing research that requires me to find a list of how many US [National Merit Scholars](http://www.nationalmerit.org/) were enrolled at each university for 2013.

I can find the 2014 list in the Annual Report the National Merit Society has on the website and I can find data pre-2013 at the Center for Measuring University Performance (at ASU). However neither an online search, the National Merit Society website, nor my university's online catalog were able to locate the Annual Report for 2013. I know this information must be out there (since the Annual Report for 2014 is a downloadable pdf), but is not easy to find. Does anybody know of a list (preferably online) of how many 2013 National Merit Scholars attended each university?

Comment: Reference requests are considered on-topic. Typically, "shopping" questions are more related to whether or not you should attend A or B. Searching for a factual reference, especially regarding the scope of academia, is acceptable here.

Comment: I see this already has an answer, but for future reference and for searchability it would be useful (IMO) to specify what nation's 'National' award is being discussed.

Comment: Added a link to the National Merit Scholarship Corporation website, which should make it completely unambiguous which program is being referred to here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Google-Fu, I believe I have found what you are looking for:

[The 2012-2013 Annual Report](http://www.limitless-horizons.org/233079285-Annual-Report-2013-National-Merit.pdf)

As a guide, someone somewhere will always want to archive something. In this case, archive.org didn't have it, but the owner of that domain, who is likely to be an awesome person in research in a few years, cached a copy of it for us.

The statement used to find this document was:

`"2012-13" national merit scholar annual report pdf`

It is important to use the years in quotes as 2013 can be used to find the current report as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you both for the comment and the information; neither myself nor a reference librarian could find this. Google-Fu indeed :)